# Select multiple records from same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to write a query that will select two different result from table.

Let us suppose that following is table sale:

```
 Supp                           items
 A                                 1
 A                                 1
 A                                 3
 A                                -1 //negative represent return item
 B                                 1
```

I want to select sum of sale products and returned products. So the following will be the result:

```
Supp  Sale  Return
A       5      1
B       1      0
```

I am trying following query but not getting desired results

```
select 
t.Supp, count(t.items)'Quantity', count(s.items)'ReturnedQuantity'  
from sale t, sale s  
where t.items='1' and s.items='-1'
group by
   t.supp,s.supp   
order by
  sum(cast(t.items as int)) desc
```

Will somebody tell me what will be query to get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      Supp
    , SUM( CASE WHEN items > 0 
                THEN items
                ELSE 0
           END
         )
      AS SoldQuantity
    , - SUM( CASE WHEN items < 0 
                  THEN items
                  ELSE 0
             END
           )
      AS ReturnedQuantity
FROM sale   
GROUP BY Supp   
ORDER BY SoldQuantity DESC         --- or ORDER BY Supp
                                   --- whatever is needed
```

---

What was wrong with the original query:

First, you use `COUNT()` when you should use `SUM()`.

Second you join two instances of table `sale`. This might have worked if you had used `t.items >0 AND s.items < 0` But it would be more complex and you would need also `t.supp = s.supp`. Unneccecarily complexity (and it may not even work even then).

Third, the `where t.items='1' and s.items='-1'` conditions does not sum any rows with items different than `1` or `-1`. And you obsiously have some different, like the `3`.

Comment: thanks!Will you please tell me.What was the wrong with my query?

Comment: this one has still negative sum for the returns, instead of positive and also it's not ordered by sale desc (I know it's minor) :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.Supp AS 'Supp', SUM(t.items) AS 'Sale', SUM(t.return_items) AS 'Return'  FROM           (
    SELECT Supp AS Supp,
    CASE WHEN items < 0 THEN 0 ELSE items END AS items,
    CASE WHEN items > 0 THEN 0 ELSE -items END AS return_items
    FROM tb_Test
) AS t
GROUP BY t.Supp
ORDER BY 'Sale' desc
```

Comment: @Zain, you do a cross join and filter on those columns that have 1 on the left and -1 on the right, but this way completely omit those that have 3. Then you group by two columns so it like you count pairs... Basically many things are wrong with your query :)